# Firebase simple query gives error: "Converting circular structure to JSON at JSON.stringify"

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to loop through a /users path and join it to my auth().listUsers result however this code:

https://github.com/QuantumInformation/svelte-fullstack-starter/blob/master/firebase_specific/functions/src/users.ts#L32

```js
export async function getSomeUsers(amount: number) {
    try {
        const listUsersResult = await admin.auth().listUsers(amount)
        const parsedUsers = listUsersResult.users.map(stripUserSensitiveInfo).map(async user => {
            console.log("try read_______________" + user.uid)
            let userProfileSnapshot = await admin
                .database()
                .ref("users/" + user.uid)
                .once("value")

            console.log("end try read_______________" + user.uid)
            return { ...user, userProfileSnapshot }
        })

        return parsedUsers
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error listing users:", error)
        throw new Error("Error users" + error)
    }
}
```

gives this error

> Converting circular structure to JSON at JSON.stringify () at stringify

but this code works fine

```js
export async function getSomeUsers(amount: number) {
    try {
        const listUsersResult = await admin.auth().listUsers(amount)


        const parsedUsers = listUsersResult.users.map(stripUserSensitiveInfo).map( user => {


            return 1
        })


        return parsedUsers
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error listing users:", error)
        throw new Error("Error users" + error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to print out userProfileSnapshot ?

Comment: Finding it hard who to give the award too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is within the embedded async calls in the `map` operator
In order to make it work, you would need to either wait for each iteration, which would also be VERY inefficient. This is because for every additional query the time taken increases Linearly.
My proposal is to convert the entire logic in a way that is scalable. This is fortunately the case with your `listAllUsers()` function that returns all the results on one call

```
export async function getSomeUsers(amount: number) {
try {
    /**
     * fetch all the users with the provided limit
     */
    const allUsers = await admin.auth().listUsers(amount)
    /**
     * loop through the returned values and create a promise to fetch
     * Each of their document
     */
    const listUsersResult = allUsers.users.map(user => {
        return admin
            .database()
            .ref("users/" + user.uid)
            .once("value")
    })
    /**
     * When all the user documents have been fetched, iterare through them and deduce their values
     */
    const parsedUsers = await Promise.all(listUsersResult).then(docSnashots => {
        return docSnashots.map(snapshot => {
            console.log("end try read_______________" + snapshot.val())
            /**
             * The records need to be matched with the original values
             */
            const originalUserData = allUsers.users.find(u => u.uid === snapshot.key)
            return { ...originalUserData, ...snapshot.val() }
        })
    })
    return parsedUsers

} catch (error) {
    console.error("Error listing users:", error)
    throw new Error("Error users" + error)
}
}
```

**NOTE** this method is more compute intensive because of the loops, but more time efficient since every read operation is independent of the other. It can be modified for situations where you're sure the read operations will always take a very short time and (Maybe) would be more resource efficient than the computation of the loops

Comment: Can you explain, please, why is that `for every additional query the time taken increases exponentially`? And in what way your code differs from the original?

Comment: await means that the code pauses and waits for the promise to resolve before resuming execution
If you're querying 1000 docs, each taking 200ms, it would take 200*1000 = 20secs

It's blocking nature means that you cannot run queries in parallel,
as opposed to if you put them in Promise.all, where they are executed in parallel and would take a considerably less time

Comment: Also, sorry for the confusion. I meant increase Linearly.
I've modified my answer

Comment: Ok but, then the `map(async user => {...})` in the original code is essentially `promises[0] = f(); ... promises[N] = f(); ...` not `results[0] = await f(); ... results[N] = await f();`. So I don't see any basis for difference in performance. Do I miss something?

Comment: Also, please check that you've correctly parsed the `userProfileSnapshot` in your original code before returning it by calling `userProfileSnapshot.val()`

Comment: This is truly an amazing answer

Comment: if i log                 console.log("snapshot" + snapshot)
I dont see the key in the log, but rather:
**{
 insertId: "000017-f635939e-c05f-486c-bf75-a9506fc0dc8a"  
 labels: {…}  
 logName: "projects/svelte-fullstack-starter/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-02-26T22:20:37.274255941Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 severity: "INFO"  
 textPayload: "snapshot[object Object]"  
 timestamp: "2020-02-26T22:20:35.673Z"  
 trace: "projects/svelte-fullstack-starter/traces/bc209378e6b0237588f023f45d5b0282"  
}**

Comment: Huh.... That's strange... Which sdk are you using?
I've just tested with some sample data and it works fine...

Comment: marked yours as answer as it seems like best solution

Answer (score 2):

Based on your 2nd code snippet, i think there is an issue in async call.
Did you try whether the async inside the map is working as expected ?.
Try like this and check.

```
    let parsedUsers = [];
    const userList = listUsersResult.users.map(stripUserSensitiveInfo);
    for (const user of userList) {
      try {
        let userProfileSnapshot = await admin
            .database()
            .ref("users/" + user.uid)
            .once("value")
        parsedUsers.push({...user, userProfileSnapshot});
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error on API', error);
      }
    }
```

Comment: thx that worked, giving me

   {
        "uid": "2l5mN3ebNOdVZqtgwW5e9sNzBzc2",
        "displayName": "tesd",
        "userProfileSnapshot": {
            "username": "ccsd12"
        }
    },

Comment: perfect. Pleasure to help.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why your code works and not mine

Comment: Inside map iteration, we can make promise wait, it will run the code continuously without waiting for the await completion even u used with async. If you want to use the async with await, then you can try Promise.all to resolve finally and update your result.

Comment: dang I didnt realise that limitation with map

Comment: everything is learning. i faced once and find a way to fix, now i happy to help you :)

Comment: Is there any advantage of Kisinga answer vs yours?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use it like this. For your second map function, it will return an array of promises. So, you will have to keep all the promises and then use `Promise.all` to resolve them.

```
return Promise.all(parsedUsers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looked at the github repo you've linked... don't really understands how do you get to the point of

> Converting circular structure to JSON at JSON.stringify () at stringify

Because code

```js
export const listUsers = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    ...
    const data = await getSomeUsers(10)
    res.json(data)
})
```

in [firebase_specific/functions/src/index.ts](https://github.com/QuantumInformation/svelte-fullstack-starter/blob/74816b4a41996862a231c265b29612988e12cd13/firebase_specific/functions/src/index.ts)
should look like

```
export const listUsers = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    ...
    const data = await Promise.all(await getSomeUsers(10))
    res.json(data)
})
```

Or, better yet, as @AlbertPinto pointed out `return parsedUsers` should be changed to `return Promise.all(parsedUsers)`

**Any way, back to the error message:**

`userProfileSnapshot` is a [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot#val) object and it, judging by the error, **has** circular references. So you probably should change

```
return { ...user, userProfileSnapshot }
```

to

```
return { ...user, userProfileSnapshot.val() }
```

or something similar, based on your needs

Comment: Thanks but the first answer didn't need to use  .val()

Comment: I'm confused... Now, when the issue of Promises is fixed, do you understand how you got the error? Because `res.json()` with array of Promises as an argument can not give you the `circular structure`. Can you explain the error, plz

Comment: cause the map wasnt running the async code immediatly or smth

Comment: "Or smth"... that's the reason I'm asking - it shouldn't be possible. (And I've tested it)

Answer (score 1):

> Converting circular structure to JSON at JSON.stringify () at stringify

This error is caused by stringifying a circular structure. A circular structure is a structure that has an attribute / deep-attribute that refers to itself.

```
const a = {}
a.b = a; // this creates a circular structure
```

**First** you should check if `stripUserSensitiveInfo` function creates a circular structure. It is possible because the error happened when `user` object is the result of the function and is returned in the first snippet.

**Second** as pointed in this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/60299145/5381781, in the first snippet the variable `parsedUsers` actually contains array of promises instead of array of user data. To resolve an array of promises, use `Promise.all()`

```
const parsedUsers = await Promise.all(listUsersResult.users
  .map(stripUserSensitiveInfo)
  .map(async user => {
    console.log("try read_______________" + user.uid);
    let userProfileSnapshot = await admin
      .database()
      .ref("users/" + user.uid)
      .once("value");

    console.log("end try read_______________" + user.uid);
    return { ...user, userProfileSnapshot };  // You might also want to tweak this structure
  }));
```

**Another one**, a little bit out of topic, assuming that `admin.database().ref("users/" + user.uid).once("value")` is a network call, you might want to use a `for...of statement` instead of map. This is to make sure your application doesn't flood the network connection by making too many network requests, depending on the value of `amount` variable.